# Dynamic object creation from JSON

Tags: java, android, json, dynamic, jackson

I have an Android app which receives a string in JSON format.

The JSON structure contains an array of JSON objects of different types.
I will create one class for each type and want to instantiate the objects directly from JSON with the help of a JSON framework.

To make it simpler, let's think of the following example:

We have two Java classes:

```
public class A
{
   public String a1 = "";

   public int a2 = 0;

}

public class B
{
   public double b1 = 0;
   public double b2 = 0;
   public double b3 = 0;
}
```

nor e.g. we have a JSON array coming in

```
[
  {
    "a1": "Teststring",
    "a2": 12
  },
  {
    "b1": 3,
    "b2": 4,
    "b3": 5
  },
  {
    "a1": "Teststring2",
    "a2": 24
  }
]
```

I don't know which, how many or in what order the JSON objects will come in. But I am able to modify their JSON representation.

One Solution I can think of:

As far as I understood from reading about frameworks, Jackson is in comparison to GSON able to do both, read specific values and generate Java instances.
So I could add type information to the JSON objects:

```
    [
  {
    "type": "A",
    "a1": "Teststring",
    "a2": 12
  },
  {
    "type": "B",
    "b1": 3,
    "b2": 4,
    "b3": 5
  },
  {
    "type": "A",
    "a1": "Teststring2",
    "a2": 24
  }
]
```

than read the value from type and then generate the right object from that.

What do you think of my approach? Is there a common solution out there for my problem?

Comment: Do you have any control over the json object sent? I mean if it is a server that sends the json responses, are you controlling the server or is it already running server?

Comment: I am controlling the server.

Comment: Then, like you said mention the type of the object you send in the json object itself. It is safe and reduce the workload at client side.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of putting everything in an array, why don't use a json object and add the objects as members to it with a generic name consisting of - lets say - the type and some index.

```
    {
        "A0":
        { ... },
        "B0":
        { ... },
        "A1":
        { ... },
    }
```

Comment: You can then iterate over the json object members and determine each of the individual types by looking at the respective key.

Answer (score 1):

If you are mixing types in the array, you would need the type information I think to keep things simple just parse the JSON to a `List<Map<String,Object>>` and while you iterate look at the type and use either

```
mapper.readValue(input, A.class)
```

or

```
mapper.readValue(input, B.class)
```

based on the the type that you encounter.

You can potentially skip this mapping step and just operate on `Map<String,Object>` too to avoid the extra overhead. Efficiency and beautiful code sometimes don't go hand in hand ;)